Adding a language rule and displaying posts with a custom taxonomy term on its archive page
The WordPress website I'm working on is available in two languages using Polylang, en-US and en-PH. I use CPT UI and have a custom taxonomy "subtopic" that is not multilingual. Under "subtopic" are terms like "copyright" and "trademark".
I intend to do the following:

If a post with the current term is available in the main language, hide the other translation, but if it is not available in the main language, show it as is (in the secondary language). I am able to do this with the below code added as a snippet:

/*
 * Query all posts versions on taxonomy archive page.
 */
function sam_modify_taxonomy_query( $query ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'pll__' ) && ! is_admin() && $query->is_tax() ) {
        $query->set('tax_query', '');
        $query->set('lang', '');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sam_modify_taxonomy_query' );



Display only posts with the current taxonomy term on its archive
page just like how categories and tags work. [This is the problem]

Below is the code I'm using in the file taxonomy-subtopic.php to achieve both, but I end up getting all posts that are assigned any "subtopic" instead of getting only the posts with the current term (e.g., "copyright" or "trademark") on the archive page.
When readers visit the "copyright" archive page, for example, they should see only posts that have the term; in the main language or the secondary language if a main language version is not available.
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

                <header class="header-title-wrapper">
                    xxx
                </header><!-- .header-title-wrapper -->

                <h2 class="widget-title"><span>All articles</span></h2>

    <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
        query_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'lang' => 'en-PH', // force querying the PH posts
            'showposts' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'subtopic',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term->term_id,
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                    )
                )
            )
        ); ?>

                <?php
                /* Start the Loop */
                while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php global $post;
                if($post_id = pll_get_post($post->ID, pll_current_language())) { // get translated post (in current language) if exists
                    $post = get_post($post_id);
                    setup_postdata($post);
                }?>
                    <?php
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format());
                    
                    ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

I would appreciate any advice or explanation that may help fix this. Thank you!

You can add taxonomy-subtopic-copyright.php and taxonomy-subtopic-trademark.php archive templates if you need that much granularity.

Hi Chris, thanks for the advice. However, I don't like the idea of having to create a custom file for every "subtopic" that might be added in the future. I also intend to apply the same property to the "artists" taxonomy, which already has over a hundred terms.

Might be an idea to add that info to your post, to make it a bit more visible. On an unrelated note: I'd steer clear of using query_posts, which lets the default query for a template run in the background, then throws it out and runs a while new query. That's hideously inefficient, it's much better to modify the main query before it's run by hooking to pre_get_posts.
